# Derived class tests. Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for : (?, ?) (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine

I have a simple structure with an abstract class, a derived class and a test. When I try to run Karma the following error is thrown:

```
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ActivationsComponent: (?, ?).
```

This is my abstract class:

```js
export abstract class DeviceDetailsWidget implements OnChanges {

  @Input() details: DeviceDetails;
  abstract visibleForTypes = [];

  constructor(
    protected el: ElementRef,
    protected constants: Constants
  ) { }
}
```

My component class:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'dd-dp-activations',
  templateUrl: './activations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activations.component.scss']
})
export class ActivationsComponent extends DeviceDetailsWidget {
  visibleForTypes = [this.constants.DEVICE_SHORT_TYPE.TOTO_SINK];
}
```

And my test:

```js
describe('ActivationsComponent', () => {
  let component: ActivationsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ActivationsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ActivationsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ActivationsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I was looking at other errors similar to this, but I couldn't figure out how to make it works.  This is not the only widget depending on this abstract class. In fact, I have a lot of widgets depending on DeviceDetailsWidget, but this is the simplest.

*Edited*: I have updated the ActivationsComponent class.

Comment: Do you mind sharing more details on `ActivationsComponent `. It could be the DI on the ActivationsComponent!

Comment: @nircraft I just added the whole class content. It is the value of the property that must be overridden (because it is an abstract property). I ran the test with no data inside the array: `visibleForTypes = []` with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a workaround than an actual solution to the issue, but the error should go away if you use `@Inject` in your base class constructor. It is a pain but a rather small one compared to creating explicit constructors on all your dependent classes. The resulting base class constructor would look like this:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(ElementRef) protected el: ElementRef,
    @Inject(Constants) protected constants: Constants
 )
```

You may have to provide `Constants` in the provider array on the object passed to `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

Comment: @Agorreca no worries ;) given that this worked for you, would you mind marking my post as answer?

Comment: Yes, of course. I thought I have done it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the constructor of DeviceDetailsWidget in ActivationsComponent like this:

```
export class ActivationsComponent extends DeviceDetailsWidget {
   constructor()
   {
     super(elementRef, constants)
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't *unless* the extending type also defines a `constructor`.

Comment: @thierno-barry I just added the whole class content. It is the value of the property that must be overridden (because it is an abstract property). There is no constructor in the child class.  I ran the test with no data inside the array: visibleForTypes = [] with the same result.